# Ajax AutoCompleteExtender with more parameters

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want to use Ajax AutoCompleteExtender for asp.net. I have some expamles but those examples use only two parameters. I want to use three parameters. Some example used a context property. I also checked but it did not work.

Can anybody help me.

Comment: Did my link to the article solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/AutoComplete_Textbox_Addtional_Parameters.aspx). It provides a complete explanation of how to use the `contextKey` property. Using `contextKey` is the only way to specify an extra parameter so I would give it another try.